# How to execute a scalar query with oci8 and ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, oci8

I'd like to select a next id from a sequence in oracle using oci8 and ruby.  What's the easist way of doing so?  Example wrong code:

```
id = @conn.exec( 'Select NEXT_ID.NEXTVAL from dual' )
```

.exec returns a cursor.  Is there an easy way of just getting the one value I need from the exec or similar method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@conn.exec('Select NEXT_ID.NEXTVAL from dual') {|row| id = row[0]}
```

You can also do

```
id = @conn.exec('Select NEXT_ID.NEXTVAL from dual').fetch[0]
```